# TensorFlow: Is there a limit to the number of categories and can it be expaned?

Tags: tensorflow

I have created a new graph/model on tensorflow for image classifying 6 categories.

All 6 categories and associated images have been placed in tf_files.

The retrain script is executed and appears to pick up all 6 categories.

However, running the label_image script only displays 5 categories.

I have tried renaming and trying a combination of 5 categories, to test if there is an issue with naming conventions of the directories.

No matter what combination I try, the script only tests for 5 categories.

How do I test images across 6 different categories?

C:\Users---\tensorflow-for-poets-2>ls tf_files/pressure_ulcers
Deep_Tissue  Stage_1  Stage_2  Stage_3  Stage_4  Unstageable

Thank you.

Comment: PS. The retrain script does seem to pick up all 6 categories. It’s just when I run the label-image script, it only shows 5 categories

Comment: The retrained_labels text file is showing all 6 labels.

Comment: Ok, I think I have resolved this myself. It may be that if the probability for a category is so low, that it is not listed by the label_image script.